# Firebase functions for loop async await

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to do a relatively simple, in theory, function using Firebase Functions.

Specifically:

- Add `+ 1` to a realtime database variable for all users
- Send a notification to all users

I'm still trying to understand `async`/`await` which is probably why I'm struggling so much with this.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
 exports.gcIncrement = functions.database
  .ref('gthreads/{threadId}/messages/{messageId}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

    const data = snapshot.val();
    const threadId = context.params.threadId;
    const uid = context.auth.uid;
    
    adb.ref('gchats/' + threadId).once('value').then(async (gchatData) => {
    const parent = gchatData.val();
    incrementUser(parent.users, uid, threadId); //parent.users is an object with 1-30 users.
    sendGCNotification(parent.users, data);
    return true;
  }).catch(error => console.log(error))
});
```

And then I have the function `incrementUser`:

```
function IncrementUser(array, uid, threadId) {
    for (const key in array) {
      if (key != uid) {
        const gcMessageRef =
        adb.ref('users/' + key + '/gthreads/' + threadId + '/' + threadId+'/unread/');
        gcMessageRef.transaction((int) => {
          return (int || 0) + 1;
      }
    }
  }
```

and the function `sendGCNotification`:

```
  function sendGCNotification(array, numbOfMsg, data) {
    let payload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'My App - ' + data.title,
        body: "This is a new notification!",
      }
    }
    const db = admin.firestore()
    for (const key in array) {
      if (!data.adminMessage) {
        if (array[key] === 0) {

          const devicesRef = db.collection('devices').where('userId', '==', key)

          const devices = await devicesRef.get();
          devices.forEach(result => {
            const tokens = [];
            const token = result.data().token;
            tokens.push(token)

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload)
          })

        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I currently get the error:

> 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.
>
> const devices = await devicesRef.get();

But even when I get it error-free, it doesn't seem work. The Firebase Functions log says:

> 4:45:26.207 PM
> gcIncrement
> Function execution took 444 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
> 4:45:25.763 PM
> gcIncrement
> Function execution started

So it seems to run as expected but not fulfill the code as expected. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All uses of `await` have to occur within the main body of a function that's marked `async`.  Your function `sendGCNotification` is not async.  You'll have to mark it async, and also make sure that any promises within it have been awaited, or return a promise that resolves when all the async work is done.

Also, in `IncrementUser` you are not handling the promise returned by gcMessageRef.transaction().  You need to handle every promise that you generate from all the async work, and make sure they are all a part of the final promise that you return or await from your top-level function.

If you want to learn more about promises and async/await in Cloud Functions code, I suggest you use my [video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/).  Specifically, the one titled "How does async/await work with TypeScript and ECMAScript 2017?".  Even if you aren't using TypeScript, async/await work the same way.